# Resizing an object in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

What I want to do is to increase the size of these boxes inplace, like if the box has a size of 100x200 i want to be 120x240 ie a 20 percent increase in size.

Resizing an croping the image will not work for all images as I am using it as a mask for another image(s) and if the position is changed the next step will not work.

I have been searching for a way to do it but was unable to find it.

I am using python 3.9.4

[image]

Comment: Could you include the code that generates the image?

Comment: @IbrahimTG99 This [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/01/opencv-center-of-contour/) helps to find the centers of your rectangles, after you do that and you find your rectangles corners [x0, y0, x1, y1] you can increase the dimensions of your masks by changing x,y to the values you want.

Comment: @sanitizedUser the image generated by me thresholding the original image and converting the pixels that are black to white so I donot know the location of these boxes. I am using this mask to pass it in inpaint funtion to inpaint those black boxes.

the problem has been solved and thank you for taking intrest in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use connected components function from OpenCV to detect the white boxes. Now once you the center, height, width of all the boxes you can simply increase the size of them and replace them on a black image.

Official documentation of the function : [Structural Analysis and Shape Descriptors](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html)

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, args["connectivity"],cv2.CV_32S)
(numLabels, labels, stats, centroids) = output
```

The above code loaded the image and finds out all the components in the image

now you can iterate over them to find the required component.

```
# loop over the number of unique connected component labels
for i in range(0, numLabels):
# if this is the first component then we examine the
# *background* (typically we would just ignore this
# component in our loop)
if i == 0:
    text = "examining component {}/{} (background)".format(
        i + 1, numLabels)
# otherwise, we are examining an actual connected component
else:
    text = "examining component {}/{}".format( i + 1, numLabels)
# print a status message update for the current connected
# component
print("[INFO] {}".format(text))
# extract the connected component statistics and centroid for
# the current label
x = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]
y = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]
w = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
h = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
area = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]
(cX, cY) = centroids[i]
```